# How to launch an application after another is logged in in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application, launcher

I have two desktop applications.
For second application to be active, first one needs to be logged in.
I have a launcher which can launch both of them simultaneously. But I want to modify it such that second application is launched when first one is logged in (As soon as it starts, it logs in automatically). How should I proceed?

Comment: And what you tried doing?

Comment: I have tried using Task Delay so that second application is launched after n seconds after first. I don't think it is the right approach.@Spawn

Comment: what do you mean by "loggedin" here?

Comment: Logged in as in signed in using a username and password. Both applications have same user name and password, but second would show error unless first is signed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After login, you should start the other application using `ProcessStartInfo`. and `Process.Start()` method.

In case that by login you mean the user enters username and password, the you cannot depend on the second application be launched by the first one, as a malicious user can run it independently. In this case, you can forward some information in the `ProcessStartInfo`'s arguments and use them in the second application as arguments to the `Main()` method. This data can be used to authenticate the user in the second application.